# How do I access value of current item when using for-each in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Using the code below, how do I access the current item in the loop without specifying $array[1]?

```
    <xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*">
        <item>https://www.example.com/_resources/data/blogs.xml</item> <!--item 1-->
        <item>https://www.example.com/_resources/data/blogs2.xml</item> <!--item 2-->
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:for-each select="$array/item">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document($array[1])/hero-image/img" /><!--How do we access value of current item without specifying $array[1]) -->
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the variable `$array` holds a sequence of `item` elements, and you want to iterate over these elements, not over their children. You have written `$array/item`, which is short for `$array/child::item`, which selects the children of the elements in the array, not the elements themselves.

Secondly, you refer to the current item as `.`. So you would want:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$array">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(.)/hero-image/img"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But that can be abbreviated to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$array/document(.)/hero-image/img"/>
```

Note: you are using XSLT 2.0+ here, and it's best to mention that in the question (or simply add the relevant tag, which I shall do for you).

Comment: when I try using  your for each code, with select="$array", I get triple the output for the first array item, double the output for the second array item, and a single output for the third array item.

Comment: I can't explain that. Sounds like you have misunderstood my answer somehow. Show us your code please.